# Java nested classes issue

Tags: java, oop, class, inner-classes

As I have recently started programming, I was a little stuck in this area of coding.

There is a programming lesson named nested classes. But when I want to use it, it actually does not do what the homework wants. Here is an example of what I need to achieve:

```
public class Zoo {
    ...
    public static class monkey {
        ...
    }
}
```

and in the main

```
Zoo zoo1 = new Zoo();
...
zoo1.monkey.setage(int);
...
```

But there is a problem here that whenever I want to call monkey from zoo1, the debugger says that it's not possible.(Remember that I want to do this without creating an instance of monkey)

Thanks in advance

Update: I am just wondering if it's a kinda language limitation, then how the oracle itself could do that rather easily with system.out.printf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`monkey` looks static to me. They should be `public` instead of `Public`, though.

I would say that `setage()` is not a static method. If that's the case, and if age is a property of a monkey, than it wouldn't make sense to call it statically -- whose age would you be setting?

The problem though is that you can't seem to be able to access the static inner class through a variable of the outer class type.

So it should be `Zoo.monkey` instead of `zoo1.monkey`.

If you just want to control scoping or naming, you can use [packages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_package).

For example, you could have the following:

```
package com.example.application.feature;

public class MyClass {
    public void f() {
        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

in a source file called `com/example/application/feature/MyClass.java`.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but the actual problem is that the debugger says that the monkey class itself is not recognized. So I can't just write: zoo1.monkey . I can still write Zoo.monkey though.

Comment: My money is on this being a deliberate limitation of the language (why access a static inner class through a specific instance of the outer class when the inner class can't access instance fields anyway?), but I could be wrong. What does the debugger say exactly?

Comment: It says the object or the field does not exist.

Comment: I'm getting `Main.java:7: error: package zoo1 does not exist..` on ideone. I'd say the language disallows what you're trying to do and the compiler is looking for something else. Either way, it would be helpful to read up on what the use cases for static inner classes are.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. Maybe we should wait a little more for the final answer(if any). BTW I'm mostly convinced with your answer, but BTW the multi level classes are still there in java packages(e.g system.console.readline and etc.)

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but you can have a `my.very.nested.package.MyClass`, without any inner classes. [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) sounds more like .NET / C# than Java, and if I recall they might differ a bit on inner class semantics.

Comment: Then can you give me an example for the nested class without the inner class? Quite appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not access the monkey class via an instance of Zoo, it would not actually make any sense to do that. If you want to access static methods of monkey from the main you can just use the example below

```
public class Zoo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Example 1
        monkey.setage(3);
        // Example 2
        Zoo.monkey.setage(3);
    }

    public static class monkey {
        private static int age;

        public static void setage(int age) {
            monkey.age = age;
        }
    }
}
```

But what are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: If you set the monkey's age outside of the instance, then how it can be refrenced to the instance itself? Well what I am trying to do is that the monkey's methods of the zoo1 instance(which is unique) should be accessed and called(if possible). Thanks again :)

Comment: If you do not want to create an instance of monkey, then there is no monkey that belongs to zoo1 instance.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I didn't see you note  "(Remember that I want to do this without creating an instance of monkey)"

sometimes before asking, searching might help you to save some time.Direct Quotion from this address: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

> Inner Classes
>
> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated
>   with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that
>   object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is
>   associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members
>   itself.
>
> Objects that are instances of an inner class exist within an instance
>   of the outer class. Consider the following classes:
>
> class OuterClass {
>       ...
>       class InnerClass {
>           ...
>       } }
>
> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance. The next figure illustrates this idea.
>
> An Instance of InnerClass Exists Within an Instance of OuterClass
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer
>   class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this
>   syntax:
>
> OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();
>
> Additionally, there are two special kinds of inner classes: local
>   classes and anonymous classes (also called anonymous inner classes).
>   Both of these will be discussed briefly in the next section.